# What to read on distributed computing

Tags: nosql, cloud, distributed, distributed-computing, distributed-transactions

I want to create a distributed application but feel that I don't have enough knowledge to do the job. I want to be able to understand how products like apache cassandra, hadoop, etc work and be able to make a choice between them.

Which books and articles should I read to get the knowlegde I need?

P.S. I have quite a good understanding of computer science, algorithms, compiler design, artificial intelligence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great links on distributed storage:

[bigtable-model-with-cassandra-and-hbase](http://horicky.blogspot.com/2010/10/bigtable-model-with-cassandra-and-hbase.html)

[hbase-architecture-101-storage](http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/10/hbase-architecture-101-storage.html)

Good book on Hadoop / HBase :  [HBase: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920014348.do) by Lars George

Comment: These are good material but unfortunately, they are lacking theoretical foundation for distributed computing which IMO is absolutely necessary to make good decisions.